# C# - No argument for required formal parameter?

Tags: c#

The error I receive is as follows: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'bloodPressureSystolicLevel' of 'VitalsForm.SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int, int)'. The error actually appears on the line where I call the method, SetOverallHypertensionLevel();

Calling the method:

```
    private void picSubmitVitals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SetOverallHypertensionLevel();
     }
```

Method:

```
    private void SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int bloodPressureSystolicLevel, int bloodPressureDiastolicLevel)
    {
        bloodPressureSystolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtSystolic);
        bloodPressureDiastolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiastolic);

        if ((bloodPressureSystolicLevel / 200) > (bloodPressureDiastolicLevel / 133))
        {
            if (bloodPressureSystolicLevel >= 160)
            {
                lblHyperStage2.ForeColor = colorSchemeIssue;
            }
            else if (bloodPressureSystolicLevel >= 140)
            {
                lblHyperStage1.ForeColor = colorSchemeIssue;
            }
            else if (bloodPressureSystolicLevel >= 120)
            {
                lblHyperPre.ForeColor = colorSchemeWarning;
            }
            else
            {
                lblHyperNormal.ForeColor = colorSchemeNormal;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                if (bloodPressureDiastolicLevel >= 100)
                {
                    lblHyperStage2.ForeColor = colorSchemeIssue;
                }
                else if (bloodPressureDiastolicLevel >= 90)
                {
                    lblHyperStage1.ForeColor = colorSchemeIssue;
                }
                else if (bloodPressureSystolicLevel >= 80)
                {
                    lblHyperPre.ForeColor = colorSchemeWarning;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblHyperNormal.ForeColor = colorSchemeNormal;
                }
```

Why isn't it recognizing the use of the parameters? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code where you call this method?

Comment: How are you calling `SetOverallHypertensionLevel`? Likely it's without a parameter.

Comment: In your question where you say " 'VitalsForm.SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int, int)' " if that is the code you are using to call the method, then it looks like you are not passing in values, but instead you are placing type `int` where variables of type `int` belong

Comment: I added it above!

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide an example? Clearly I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Jen, you are also performing integer division, which is unlikely to be yielding the results that your logic is expecting. For example, bloodPressureSystolicLevel / 200 is going to return an integer. If bloodPressureSystolicLevel was 500, it would return 2, not 2.5. (I don't know typical values for these types of stats, so sorry if 500 is ridiculous as an example value)

Comment: @DanielMann, sure. The issue here is that 180 / 200 == 0 when you are performing integer division, so unless bloodPressureDiastolicLevel  can be negative, you can never enter that if block.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int bloodPressureSystolicLevel, int bloodPressureDiastolicLevel)
{
    bloodPressureSystolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtSystolic);
    bloodPressureDiastolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiastolic);
```

should likely be converted to:

```
private void SetOverallHypertensionLevel()
{
    var bloodPressureSystolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtSystolic);
    var bloodPressureDiastolicLevel = Convert.ToInt32(txtDiastolic);
```

since it looks like you want **variables** not **parameters**.

*If you do that your `SetOverallHypertensionLevel();` call will work.*

Comment: That does work to get rid of the error on the call, but then my if statements don't work.

Comment: @Jen - Your if statement probably doesn't work as intended because you are dividing an int by an int. That will produce truncated int results. Divide by `200.0` and `133.0` and that will force the calcuations to be floating point, and thus more comparable.

Comment: @Jen The way StackOverflow works is that you should ask one question per post. Once that question is answered (`Why isn't it recognizing the use of the parameters?`) you should ask a **separate question** if you have a different question (like the unhandled exception).

Answer (score 1):

When you call your method

```
SetOverallHypertensionLevel();
```

you need to pass in the required arguments for the parameters defined in your method signature.

```
SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int bloodPressureSystolicLevel, int bloodPressureDiastolicLevel)
```

So an example of a correct call of that method would be:

```
SetOverallHypertensionLevel(1,1);
```

You just need to provide the `int` values required by your method.

Comment: In this case the values will vary depending on user input, so I can't hard code integers (see the Convert and If / else-if statements above). If I use SetOverallHypertensionLevel(int bloodPressureSystolicLevel, int bloodPressureDiastolicLevel); it won't work, or if I try SetOverallHypertensionLevel(bloodPressureSystolicLevel, bloodPressureDiastolicLevel);

Comment: Or, remove the two arguments from the method signature, since the values for them are populated in the first two lines of the method (which would overwrite passed in values anyway).

Comment: @hatchet, that gets rid of the parameter error, but then the populated values run into an unhandled exception.

Comment: mjwills answer is the correct answer. If you follow that, then the next possible problem is whether `txtSystolic` and `txtDiastolic` are declared and populated properly elsewhere, but since you didn't include that code, it's hard to say. That would be a separate question.

Comment: @mjwills, the method still wasn't working, so it didn't solve my problem. I have made those changes, though.       hatchet, I do have those declared and populated elsewhere, so I'll work on moving them to a broader class. Thank you!

Comment: @hatchet I think that [mjwills's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) answer is one that goes beyond answering the OP's original question, and to be clear, I think that is awesome and very valuable for Jen. In my answer, I was directly focusing on the limited scope of the original question of what caused the error. I'm not trying to say my answer is better; if anything, I agree that mjwills's is better. But, I answered this way thinking about how people in the future would probably end up here because they searched for that error message. And, I wanted to directly address the cause.

Comment: @Jen yes, I agree that you should not hard code the integers. What I wanted to do was provide an "example" that directly showed how to provide what is required to address the error you were experiencing. I figured that you would be able to take it from there or ask more questions to progress further. And, I'm glad to see that you were able to.